# EMail Signing (Outlook) Using Smartcard Minidriver [Windows]

Tags: outlook, smartcard, cryptoapi

I'm developing a Smart card Minidriver and I'm trying to Sign an Email using Outlook 2007.
I have implemented all of the necessary functions in the minidriver.

I'm able to create a "Smartcard User" certificate and save it and it's private key on the smartcard (using Microsoft Certificate Services via the Minidriver).

- When I try to sign an EMail via
  Outlook I'm getting Error Message
  (Internal Error), the last call to the minidriver is for ReadFile with "cmapfile"
- When I try to sign
  an EMail via Outlook with a
  difference non-smartcard certificate
  it's work fine.
- When I try to sign a
  Data using CryptoAPI (based on Windows SDK Sample) it's working
  fine.

I'm using Windows 7.

someone got any idea how to debug this issue?

I tried to enable the CAPI2 eventlog, it don't give me any good information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CP_CARD_PIN_INFO property in **CardGetProperty**
its field **dwChangePermission** was set to 0 and the valid values are 1-8

Comment: if you can tell the step by step procedure of writing the certificate to .net smartcard using minidriver it will be really greatful.

Comment: did you check out the following links: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281245 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257480 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905527.aspx